# Scroll View inside xml Contains 2 expandablelistview doesn't scroll

Tags: java, android

I have just created an xml File which contains 2 expandable list view and one grid view I need when I expand list items the scrollView scroll the screen as my scrollView in this xml doesn't work,I mean When I expand two expandable list view it fills the screen and the screen doesn't scrolls down
this is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scr"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="abtech.waiteriano.com.waitrer.MainPaymentActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#dedede">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
            android:background="#ffffff">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/checkNoET"
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView7"
                android:editable="false"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="505050505050"
                android:textSize="10dp">

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/checkNo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/checkNoET"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkNoET"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView7"
                android:text="Check#"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkNoET"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/checkNoET"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/check" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/checkNoET"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkNoET"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:editable="false"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:text="5"
                android:textSize="10dp">

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
                android:text="Coves"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView8"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/editText"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/covers" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/tableNo"
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/checkNoET"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView7"
                android:editable="false"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:text="25"
                android:textSize="10dp">

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView13"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tableNo"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tableNo"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkNo"
                android:text="Table"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView9"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/checkNoET"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/tablepay" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText14"
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tableNo"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tableNo"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:editable="false"
                android:text="15/10/2017 03:15PM"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView10"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText14"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/editText14"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/calendar" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:background="#ffffff">

            <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/parentList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ExpandableListView>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout3"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#ffffff">

            <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/parentList2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ExpandableListView>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="220dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rl1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#ffffff">

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/paymentsTypeGV"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:columnWidth="80dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
                android:numColumns="4"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:verticalSpacing="5dp"></GridView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

any suggestion here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html) instead of ScrollView. Although it's always recommended that you should use a single ListView or [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) with [different view types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type).

> NestedScrollView is just like ScrollView, but it supports acting as
>   both a nested scrolling parent and child on both new and old versions
>   of Android. Nested scrolling is enabled by default.